# How to get rid of incorrect syntax error in sql

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetValues @ValueName nvarchar(256)
AS
    WITH tmpTable AS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE (Value = @ValueName AND Message IS NOT NULL)
    )
    SELECT 
        Message, COUNT(Message)
    FROM 
        tmpTable
    GROUP BY 
        Message
GO;

EXEC GetValues @ValueName = 'myvalue';
```

When I do I'm getting a following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetValues, Line 11 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near ';'

I can't understand where the error is coming from. Can someone help?

I'm running this query in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Since `;` is optional have you tried removing each one in turn to see which is the cause? It's going to be `GO;` - `GO` is not part of T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

GO is not a SQL command.
Only SQL command can require a ";"

GO is a command destinate to be executed by SSMS and not by SQL Server.

GO is a separator of batch commands.

Go says to SSMS throw the command to the SQL Server and when it returns, continue to throw the commands until a new GO statement is find.